# Laravel laradock Unable to connect localhost

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx, laradock

After installing `Docker` in `ubuntu` and adding `laradock` to an existing project, I run this below command to start using `laradock`:

```bash
docker-compose up -d nginx mysql phpmyadmin workspace
```

result:

```
Creating laradock_mysql_1            ... done
Creating laradock_docker-in-docker_1 ... done
Creating laradock_workspace_1        ... done
Creating laradock_phpmyadmin_1       ... done
Creating laradock_php-fpm_1          ... done
Creating laradock_nginx_1            ... done
```

now after running `docker-compose exec bash` command I served `laravel` into that

```bash
docker-compose exec workspace bash
root@b3c88be3e389:/var/www# php artisan serve

   INFO  Server running on [http://127.0.0.1:8000].  

  Press Ctrl+C to stop the server
```

when I clicked on IP address, I get this message in browser:

```
Unable to connect

Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1:8000.

    The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
    If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the web.
```

`docker-compose ps` command result:

```
           Name                          Command               State                                                                    Ports                                                                 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
laradock_docker-in-docker_1   dockerd-entrypoint.sh            Up      2375/tcp, 2376/tcp                                                                                                                     
laradock_mysql_1              docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld      Up      0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp,:::3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp                                                                                    
laradock_nginx_1              /docker-entrypoint.sh /bin ...   Up      0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp,:::443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp,:::80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:81->81/tcp,:::81->81/tcp                               
laradock_php-fpm_1            docker-php-entrypoint php-fpm    Up      9000/tcp                                                                                                                               
laradock_phpmyadmin_1         /docker-entrypoint.sh apac ...   Up      0.0.0.0:8081->80/tcp,:::8081->80/tcp                                                                                                   
laradock_workspace_1          /sbin/my_init                    Up      0.0.0.0:2222->22/tcp,:::2222->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp,:::3000->3000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3001->3001/tcp,:::3001->3001/tcp,              
                                                                       0.0.0.0:4200->4200/tcp,:::4200->4200/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5173->5173/tcp,:::5173->5173/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8001->8000/tcp,:::8001->8000/tcp,          
                                                                       0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp,:::8080->8080/tcp
```

`nginx` definition into `docker-compose.yml`:

```
nginx:
  build:
    context: ./nginx
    args:
      - CHANGE_SOURCE=${CHANGE_SOURCE}
      - PHP_UPSTREAM_CONTAINER=${NGINX_PHP_UPSTREAM_CONTAINER}
      - PHP_UPSTREAM_PORT=${NGINX_PHP_UPSTREAM_PORT}
      - http_proxy
      - https_proxy
      - no_proxy
  volumes:
    - ${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}:${APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}${APP_CODE_CONTAINER_FLAG}
    - ${NGINX_HOST_LOG_PATH}:/var/log/nginx
    - ${NGINX_SITES_PATH}:/etc/nginx/sites-available
    - ${NGINX_SSL_PATH}:/etc/nginx/ssl
  ports:
    - "${NGINX_HOST_HTTP_PORT}:80"
    - "${NGINX_HOST_HTTPS_PORT}:443"
    - "${VARNISH_BACKEND_PORT}:81"
  depends_on:
    - php-fpm
  networks:
    - frontend
    - backend
```

and `nginx` Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:alpine

LABEL maintainer="Mahmoud Zalt <mahmoud@zalt.me>"

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/

# If you're in China, or you need to change sources, will be set CHANGE_SOURCE to true in .env.

ARG CHANGE_SOURCE=false
RUN if [ ${CHANGE_SOURCE} = true ]; then \
    # Change application source from dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org to aliyun source
    sed -i 's/dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/mirrors.aliyun.com/' /etc/apk/repositories \
;fi

RUN apk update \
    && apk upgrade \
    && apk --update add logrotate \
    && apk add --no-cache openssl \
    && apk add --no-cache bash

RUN apk add --no-cache curl

RUN set -x ; \
    addgroup -g 82 -S www-data ; \
    adduser -u 82 -D -S -G www-data www-data && exit 0 ; exit 1

ARG PHP_UPSTREAM_CONTAINER=php-fpm
ARG PHP_UPSTREAM_PORT=9000

# Create 'messages' file used from 'logrotate'
RUN touch /var/log/messages

# Copy 'logrotate' config file
COPY logrotate/nginx /etc/logrotate.d/

# Set upstream conf and remove the default conf
RUN echo "upstream php-upstream { server ${PHP_UPSTREAM_CONTAINER}:${PHP_UPSTREAM_PORT}; }" > /etc/nginx/conf.d/upstream.conf \
    && rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

ADD ./startup.sh /opt/startup.sh
RUN sed -i 's/\r//g' /opt/startup.sh
CMD ["/bin/bash", "/opt/startup.sh"]

EXPOSE 80 81 443
```

`laradock` env:

```
# All volumes driver
VOLUMES_DRIVER=local

# All Networks driver
NETWORKS_DRIVER=bridge
```

Comment: Your `docker-compose ps` provides some clue what might be happening. It says `0.0.0.0:8001->8000/tcp,:::8001->8000/tcp`. That means it's mapping the container port 8000 to the host port 8001. Should you be opening your browser to http://127.0.0.1:8081 then?

Comment: @jcragun for `http://127.0.0.1:8001/` address i get the same message

Comment: `now after running docker-compose exec bash command I served laravel into that`  ===>>> don't serve Laravel from your workspace container, you have `nginx` to do that. Open `nginx/sites` in your explorer, see what's in there. You probably have something like 'laravel.example.conf', copy that and make it 'your project.conf'. Edit 'yourprokect.conf' and apply a proper address, this will be what you access in your browser. Then `docker-compose down` and bring your containers back up in the same way you did before. Try to access your project and let's hear the results